# arrays of arrays with different length in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

My Question is can we declare arrays in this passion

```
int college[][][];
```

it contains 3 blocks Departments, Students, Marks

I need 5 Students in one Department and 6 Students in another Department

Can we declares arrays like this. If so how?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Comment: Array is not the correct way to do what you want. You should create a class for `Department`, and `Students`.

Comment: Also go by the name of "jagged arrays".

Answer (score 1):

```
int college[][][] = new int[3];
college[0] = new int[5];
college[1] = new int[6];
...
college[0][0] = new int[count_marks_dept1_student1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you should ask yourself if you shouldn't be using object-oriented programming techniques instead.

For example:

```
int departments = 5; // 5 departments
int[][][] college = new int[departments][][];

int students = 20; // 20 students in first department
college[0] = new int[students][];

int marks = 10; // 10 marks for first student in first department
college[0][0] = new int[marks];
college[0][0][0] = 3; // first mark for first student in first department

students = 17; // 17 students in second
college[1] = new int[students][];

// and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to store this in a 3D-array you can do it the following way for 2 departments:

```
int college[][][] = new int[] {new int[5], new int[6]}
```

But it would be a far better approach to handle this in separate classes for `Department` and `Student`. Is there a special requirement why you need to handle this in arrays?